# Activity Log is not Inserted in Nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I am using Nopcommerce 2.65.
I have created new page at admin side of Nopcommerce.
Now I am trying to add Log of that page in Activity Log.
but In Activity log Record is not Inserted because in Insert method it finds Systemkeyword and it found NULL

I am calling Insert Activity Method Like:

```
 _customerActivityService.InsertActivity("AddNewQuote", _localizationService.GetResource("Custom.ActivityLog.AddQuote"), quote.Id);
```

At Definition side of InsertActivityLog

```
var activityType = activityTypes.ToList().Find(at => at.SystemKeyword == systemKeyword);
            if (activityType == null || !activityType.Enabled)
                return null;
```

Please Suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the activity type record with this system name "AddNewQuote" to the [ActivityLogType] table